# Custom reverse function for lists

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to scala and want to implement a generic reverse function in functional style. I want the function in following format

```
def customReverse[T](list: List[T]) : List[T] ={
// not implemented yet
}
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? If yes, what does it say, and what line does it occur on? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? If yes, what result do you expect and why do you expect that result, what result do you get instead and why is that result not the correct one? Is the behavior you are observing not the behavior you are expecting? If yes, what behavior do you expect and why do you expect it, what behavior do you observe instead and why is that behavior not the correct one?

Comment: [so] is not a code-writing service (those do exist, they are called "programmers" and you can hire them), you need to show some effort. Please, read [ask] and learn to construct a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Reversing can be done pretty easily with a fold.

```
def customReverse[T](list: List[T]): List[T] =
  list.foldLeft[List[T]](Nil) { (a, b) => b :: a }
```

`foldLeft` places a binary operation between each pair of elements in the list. So if we give our function `{ (a, b) => b :: a }` a name, `<>` (using an infix name makes everything look prettier when doing these sorts of reductions), the fold left looks something like this (pseudo-code, of course)

```
customReverse(List(1, 2, 3))
List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(Nil)(<>)
(((Nil <> 1) <> 2) <> 3)
((List(1) <> 2) <> 3)
(List(2, 1) <> 3)
List(3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach

```
def customReverse[T](list: List[T]) : List[T] ={
 list match{
 case Nil => Nil
 case x :: xs => customReverse(xs) :+ x
 }
}
```

On invoking the function `customReverse(List(1,2,3,4))` , you will get an output

```
List(4,3,2,1)
```

Comment: Reversing linked list in quadratic time, seriously?